# Heat Color Densities in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, square

I am trying to build a type of color density plot similar to the one here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/generating-visually-appealing-density-heat-maps-in-r

But with different types of data that goes into it. My real data has a bunch of rows but for example I have code that is put into a data frame that is X, Y, Score and I want to have a color density plot using these static X, Y buckets. Is that possible?

```
X=seq(0,10,by=1)
Y=seq(50,60,by=1)
total=expand.grid(X,Y)
nrow(total)
total$score=runif(nrow(total), min=0, max=100)
range(total$score)
head(total)

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "yellow", "red"))(n = 100)
col_breaks = c(seq(0,100,length=100))
col=data.frame(as.character(my_palette),col_breaks)
col$num=row.names(col)
head(col)
col$col_breaks=round(col$col_breaks,0)
names(col)[1]="hex"

total$round=round(total$score)
total$color=as.character(col$hex[match(total$round,col$col_breaks)])

plot(total$Var1,total$Var2,col=total$color,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(50,60))
```

I am not trying to hexbin or anything confine into boxes, figured that out using conditional rect() with colors but wondering with this type of data if there is a way for it to sort of be more of a freeflowing shape of heat similar to this:

[image: a busy cat]

Or does it need to be continuous data to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can do this in `ggplot`.

Basically you can use `geom_raster` to fill in the tiles with an interpolate option so it won't look "blocky". You can then set the gradient to what you want. So for example, based on the sample data you gave me I have set the low, mid, high colours to be blue, white and red respectively. It would simply be the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(total, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill=score), interpolate=TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(0,100), low="blue", mid="white", high="red", midpoint = 50)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!